# Using std::priority_queue with std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, reference, stl

I have a `std::vector<Server>` which I populate and then do not ever change in the rest of my program.

I want to use these in a priority queue, but I need identity semantics; copying the `Server` objects creates new objects that I can't use properly. Basically:

- the `Server` objects are orderable by a `done` member (type `double`, representing a time), and `Server` implements `operator <` and `operator >`
- I will repeatedly put `Server` objects in the priority queue and take them out
- This allows me to take one out of the priority queue that has the earliest `done` time
- I never put a `Server` into the queue twice (if it matters)
- The `done` time never changes for a `Server` while it is in the priority queue, only when it is outside the queue
- I need to be able to access a `Server` object directly when I take it out of the queue, rather than through the `vector`

I have read that [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) can be used in `std::vector` and other containers. But I can't seem to get the priority queue to recognize the ordering relation of my `Server` objects when they are in a `reference_wrapper`.

Is there a way to fix? Here is the relevant part of my program:

```
class Server {
private:
    ...          // other members
    double done; // done time
public:
    ...
    double next_free(void) const { return done; }
    bool operator < (const Server& other) const {
        return done < other.done;
    }
    bool operator > (const Server& other) const {
        return done > other.done;
    }
};

...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    
    ...
    
    std::vector<Server> servers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        Server server(i,i,0.01);
        servers.push_back(server);
    }
    typedef std::reference_wrapper<Server> ServerRef;

    std::priority_queue<ServerRef, std::vector<ServerRef>, std::greater<ServerRef>> pq;
    for (auto it = servers.begin(); it < servers.end(); ++it)
    {
        pq.push(std::ref(*it));
    }

...
}
```

If I comment out the for loop containing `pq.push` then my program compiles, but otherwise I get a bunch of errors from clang, starting with:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:742:21: error: 
      invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::__1::reference_wrapper<Server>' and 'const
      std::__1::reference_wrapper<Server>')
        {return __x > __y;}
                ~~~ ^ ~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::reference_wrapper` does not have have comparison operators defined for it so you have to provide your own.  You can do that using a lambda expression like:

```
auto ServerRefCmp = [](const ServerRef& lhs, const ServerRef& rhs) { return lhs.get() > rhs.get(); };
```

And then you can provide that to the `priority_queue` like:

```
std::priority_queue<ServerRef, std::vector<ServerRef>, decltype(ServerRefCmp)> pq;
```

---

If you don't want to use a lambda exprssion you can write your own functor like:

```
struct ServerRefCmp
{
    bool operator()(const ServerRef& lhs, const ServerRef& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.get() > rhs.get();
    }
};

std::priority_queue<ServerRef, std::vector<ServerRef>, ServerRefCmp> pq;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just had to define `operator >` for ServerRef:

```
typedef std::reference_wrapper<Server> ServerRef;

bool operator >(const ServerRef& lhs, const ServerRef& rhs)
{
    return lhs.get() > rhs.get();
}
```

Comment: Overloading operators for types you do not own can lead to very hard to find bugs later on down he road if owner of that type decides to provide that operator.

Comment: ah... yeah, it smelled fishy, but I didn't know the right way to do it.

Comment: ...although `ServerRef` is mine... isn't it?

Comment: `ServerRef` is not yours.  It's a `std::reference_wrapper` to your custom type, but `std` owns the code for `reference_wrapper`, and that is the thing you wrote the operator for.  I have added an answer to show how to do this without overloading the operator.